# Find all constants where a matrix is symmetric

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

I have a matrix like below:

$$M = \begin{bmatrix} 2 && a-2b+c && 2a+b+c \\ 3 && 5 && -2 \\ 0 && a+c && 7\end{bmatrix}$$

In order for the matrix to be symmetric, the following constraints on $a$, $b$, and $c$ must hold:

$$a-2b+c = 3 \\ 2a+b+c = 0 \\ a+c = -2$$

How would I find the domain of $a$, $b$, and $c$? The set of equations above can form a matrix, and solving the system would give an individual value for each, but this gives a lone example of values that work, how would I find the range?

Am I reading too much into the question? Are the set of equations I've provided the ranges?

Comment: The term "domain" and "range" are not really applicable in this situation.  What you will find are the set of all such $a,b,c$ such that your matrix is symmetric.  As you say, you can form a system of equations and solve using your favorite method.  $\left[\begin{smallmatrix}1&-2&1\\2&1&1\\1&0&1\end{smallmatrix}\right] \left[\begin{smallmatrix}a\\b\\c\end{smallmatrix}\right]= \left[\begin{smallmatrix}3\\0\\-2\end{smallmatrix}\right]$.  The solution set of this system of equations (equivalently matrix equation) will be *all* solutions.  Possibly one or infinitely many, depending on the result.

Comment: The coeffiicient of $c$ in your first equation does not match what is in the matrix. Which one is the typo?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I guess that you are overthinking it. You've found that system correctly. In fact: $$\begin{cases} a-2b+c = 3 \\ 2a+b+c = 0 \\ a+c = -2 \end{cases} \implies \begin{bmatrix} 1 & -2 & 1 \\ 2 & 1 & 1 \\ 1 & 0 & 1 \end{bmatrix} \begin{bmatrix} a \\ b \\ c \end{bmatrix}  = \begin{bmatrix} 3 \\ 0 \\ -2\end{bmatrix}, $$
and since the determinant of that matrix is non zero, we have an unique solution $(a,b,c)$ for that system. In other words, we have only one choice of $a,b$ and $c$ to make the initial matrix symmetric.

Comment: Is this system indeed correct? OP's 1,2 position has $a-2b+2c$, but the first equation OP wrote (and that this answer uses) has $a-2b+c$.

Comment: Since the last equation reads $a+c=-2$, the lower right entry of your matrix should be $1$.

Comment: Fixed , thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Hint:

$$a-2b+c = 3 \\ 2a+b+c = 0 \\ a+c = -2$$

Rank of coefficient matrix is full i.e. $3$, Hence system has a unique solution.
Now eliminate $b$ from 1),2) then you will get a new equation in $a,c$ then solve equation with 3). you will get the value of $a,b,c$.

Answer (score 2):

Just for variety, avoiding explicit linear algebra:

It is suggested to me to subtract $a+c$ from $a-2b+c$, because that simultaneously eliminates $a$ and $c$. By the symmetry, the result should be $3-(-2)$. So $$(a-2b+c)-(a+c)=5$$ $$-2b=5$$ $$b=-\frac{5}{2}$$

Now subtracting two expressions like $$(2a+b+c)-2(a+c)=0-2(-2)$$ $$b-c=4$$ so $c=b-4=-\frac{13}{2}$. And solving for $a$ is now trivial.

Comment: Yes, finding a unique solution to the system of equations provided in OP seemed trivial, I'm not sure why the question asked me to find *all* a, b, and c where the matrix is symmetric. It makes it sound like there's more than one solution.

Comment: Math questions are often worded that way so as to not give away any extra information. It's up to you to establish there is exactly one solution, instead of zero, or more than one.